# Time Complexity of Linked Lists

Tags: python

Looking to visualize how linked lists find one another. I understand that one node points to another but it then has to find that node as each node does not necessarily follow the previous one physically in
memory. **So would that mean that when traversing a linked list it may have to jump past other nodes before they find the next node in the sequence?**
If that's the case 0(n) when locating an element is incorrect. I know is it correct but I'm trying to visualize the above

Thanks in advance

Comment: Memory is random access; *given* the reference to an object, you can see the object itself in O(1) time. But reaching any given reference in the first place takes O(n) time, because you have to traverse every preceding reference first.

Comment: and (n) just refers to worst case scenario. For example if a Linked List had 100 elements, it would be 0(100)?

Comment: @Continuit O(100) doesn't make any sense. That fundamentally misunderstands what Big-Oh notation describes, it describes how an algorithm *scales*

Comment: Yes but n refers to maximum amount of actions it would take, so it does make sense

Comment: When searching a linked list, you may find a match on the very first node you check or you may not find it until you get to the last one.  The average number of nodes you need to check is n/2, but the `/2` part is ignored in Big-O calculations.

Comment: (n) has to mean to something and from my understanding n refers to the number (in this case) of nodes in the linked list. If there are 100 nodes and the last contains the value we want, we would perform 100 actions to get there?

Comment: @Continuit **no it doesn't**. Seriously, look up the definition, *that does not make sense*. Big-oh notation isn't telling you "the number of actions to perform your algorithm*. It is a description of **how an algorithm scales asymptotically**. This is *a fundamental thing to understand*.

Comment: Binary search is a different beast. O(n) in linear. Average linked list search is n/2, add 1 to n and average search time always goes up by .5. Binary search is average log(n). As n grows, you need a lot of them to get a little move in search time.

Comment: There's a slight wrinkle: if you get to pick the index first, *then* ask how long it takes to get there, it's an O(1) operation. If you want to get the 500th element of a list, it takes the same amount of time no matter how long that list is. Getting node 500 is just as fast in a 500-item list as it is in a 10,000,000-item list.... (1/2)

Comment: @tdelenay Thanks for explaining that. Seems I have look back in Big-O notation. I watched a CS50 lecture on it, but as it was the first time I ever heard it seems I need a few more visits

Comment: ... but if you *can't* pick the index first, all you can say is that finding an arbitrary item in a list takes O(n) time, because you potentially need to look at every item in an *n*-item list. That clearly takes longer for the 10,000,000-item list than it does for the 500-item list.

Comment: You can check out some wikipedia sources [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#:~:text=Big%20O%20notation%20is%20a,a%20particular%20value%20or%20infinity.) and [Binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). There is advanced mathematics behind this stuff and I am more on the hand-wavy side myself.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Even the format of your comment shows how passive aggressive you're being. I can tell you're raging at your keyboard right now. The way you convey information is just as important as the information itself.

Answer (score 1):

A linked list looks like this:

```
    head
     |
     v
   +--+-+    +--+-+    +--+-+    +--+-+
   | 1|*|--->| 2|*|--->| 3|*|--->| 4|/|
   +--+-+    +--+-+    +--+-+    +--+-+
```

which represents the following code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


head = Node(1)
head.next = Node(2)
head.next.next = Node(3)
head.next.next.next = Node(4)
```

If all you have is `head` to start with, it necessarily takes O(n) time to reach an arbitrary node in the list, because the only reference to that node is stored in the preceding node, which is only reachable from *its* preceding node, etc. There's no "skipping" in a linked list.

There are data structure that store multiple links that can speed up access, at the cost of increasing the number of space required.

---

O(n) does not mean *every* operation takes *cn* steps for some constant *c*; it means that in the *worst* case, there is at least *one* operation that takes *cn* steps.

Comment: It's the reference part that confuses me. How could i visualize that?

Comment: @Continuit visualize what? I think the important thing for you to understand is that in modern computers with random-access memory, data is read in effectively the same amount of time regardless of the physical location. Back in the old days, that wasn't actually the case, but it is now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't think that's relevant. The point is that you don't even know the address of the last node in the list until you look at the next-to-last node, and you don't know *its* address until you look at the next-to-next-to-last node, etc.

Comment: @chepner If it's a double-ended linked list. Would the first node contain information on the last?

Comment: @chepner and thank you for the answers

Comment: @Continuit a circular doubly linked list would

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "double-ended" linked list, but a common thing to do is to store one extra reference with the list, to the last node in addition to the first node. That doesn't speed up most operations (you still have to walk the list from beginning to somewhere in the middle), but it makes *appending* an item to the list an O(1) operation, rather than O(n), because you already start with a reference to the end, rather than having to walk the list to find it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you

Comment: I did mean doubly-ended, oops

Answer (score 1):

What you basically have in each element of a linked list is a a tuple of (value, pointerToMemoryPosition) - with the pointerToMemoryPosition basically being an intrinsic value for the system.

By having the direct pointer to the next node without the need to look it up, you are able to jump to the correct position in O(1). It does not matter if the position in memory is 0xAAAAA or 0xCFA11. You are always able to jump directly to the correct position.

If you go to the successors succesor you will have to do two jumps. But you do not have to traverse through the memory regions between those two elements.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: So the computer knows where every position in memory is, the goal is just to find the right one. So once it knows the position is " 0xAAAAA" then it would take O(1)?

Comment: Totally correct.